# How to fix Node "options" does not exist for Node "Drupal\Core\Template\TwigNodeTrans"

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

After installing Drupal 8 as in the this [Local Development Guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/official_docs/en/_local_development_guide.html)
I successfully completed the steps up-to Install Drupal section. When I open it in browser I only get 
`The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.`

After setting `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';` in `settings.php` I managed to get the following error trace

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Twig\Error\SyntaxError: An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Node "options" does not exist for Node "Drupal\Core\Template\TwigNodeTrans".") in "core/themes/bartik/templates/block--system-menu-block.html.twig". in Twig\Environment->compileSource() (line 798 of /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php). 

Drupal\Core\Template\TwigNodeTrans->compile(Object) (Line: 118)
Twig\Node\Node->compile(Object) (Line: 103)
Twig\Compiler->subcompile(Object) (Line: 38)
Twig\Node\BlockNode->compile(Object) (Line: 118)
Twig\Node\Node->compile(Object) (Line: 118)
Twig\Node\Node->compile(Object) (Line: 103)
Twig\Compiler->subcompile(Object) (Line: 107)
Twig\Node\ModuleNode->compileTemplate(Object) (Line: 77)
Twig\Node\ModuleNode->compile(Object) (Line: 92)
Twig\Compiler->compile(Object) (Line: 772)
Twig\Environment->compile(Object) (Line: 793)
Twig\Environment->compileSource(Object) (Line: 482)
Twig\Environment->loadClass(&#039;__TwigTemplate_8a36b536e32bf0b1914811d79e1edf0e487059aa5ccf779f9b95f53355e28ac3&#039;, &#039;core/themes/bartik/templates/block--system-menu-block.html.twig&#039;, NULL) (Line: 445)
Twig\Environment->loadTemplate(&#039;core/themes/bartik/templates/block--system-menu-block.html.twig&#039;) (Line: 64)
twig_render_template(&#039;core/themes/bartik/templates/block--system-menu-block.html.twig&#039;, Array) (Line: 384)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render(&#039;block&#039;, Array) (Line: 437)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 450)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 490)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array, &#039;html&#039;, NULL, 1) (Line: 64)
__TwigTemplate_b957555d616a9ab14351dcabd437c24eff5410fef69055c9c4fd4e0c505e8ee5->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 443)
Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 414)
Twig\Template->display(Array) (Line: 422)
Twig\Template->render(Array) (Line: 64)
twig_render_template(&#039;core/themes/bartik/templates/page.html.twig&#039;, Array) (Line: 384)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render(&#039;page&#039;, Array) (Line: 437)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 490)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array, &#039;html&#039;, NULL, 1) (Line: 102)
__TwigTemplate_a886be0944b0f166f485440f11e78d43e4d22671d48ee10699c8dcf8db39b676->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 443)
Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 414)
Twig\Template->display(Array) (Line: 422)
Twig\Template->render(Array) (Line: 64)
twig_render_template(&#039;core/themes/classy/templates/layout/html.html.twig&#039;, Array) (Line: 384)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render(&#039;html&#039;, Array) (Line: 437)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 147)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 148)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, &#039;kernel.view&#039;, Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, &#039;kernel.view&#039;, Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(&#039;kernel.view&#039;, Object) (Line: 156)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 184)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->fetch(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 121)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->lookup(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 75)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 693)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Considering an error during installation I reinstalled `ddev` and `Drupal` again from scratch except for `Docker`. But I still end up there. My OS is Arch(Manjaro) and Docker containers for this is from ddev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Twig error, users have started to report this issue using Drupal 8.6.15 & Twig 1.40.ish.

Please downgrade your twig version as explained in [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3051269) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2019-04-28/twig-error-in-any-theme-after-updating-to-drupal-8615)

**Update**: Set your version from v1.40.0 => v1.40.1 that solved the problem ( https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/commit/732c489693fab432bcaf9ccbb1c53b91fe135700 )